# Given three infinite languages L1 L2 L3 over the same Alphabet, that do not intirsect. could one be TR and the other TD and the third neither?

Tags: complexity-theory

$\sum$  is the Alphabet of three infinite languages $L_{1},L_{2}$  and  $L_{3}$

where $L_{1}\cup L_{2} \cup  L_{3}=\sum^{*}$

and

$L_{1} \cap L_{2} = \emptyset$, $L_{2} \cap L_{3} =\emptyset$ and $L_{1} \cap L_{3} = \emptyset$

is it possible that $L_{1}$
is Decidable, $L_{2}$ is Turing Recognizable but not Decidable

and $L_{3}$ is not Turing Recognizable?

If so please give an example, if not why?

Now, it is most likely this is possible, I just had trouble finding an example.

Comment: How does this differ from [your previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89132/755)?   What have you tried?  Have you tried adapting the answer there?  Where did you get stuck?   We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Hint: first find a way to partition $\Sigma^*$ in three decidable parts. Then choose carefully from them. Once you choose $L_1$ and $L_2$ from parts $1,2$, take $L_3$ to be their complement.

Comment: It's different by that the languages are infinite. Helping me solve exercises might very much help me, if the answers were well explained, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L_{1}$={Set Of All Regular Languages},

$L_{2}\cup L_{3}$= $\bar{L}_{1}$

$L_{2}$={Set Of All Non Regular Languages That Are Recognizable By Turing Machines.}

$L_{1}$ is Decidable, $L_{2}$ Recognizable but not decidable, and $L_{3}$ is not recognizable. Languages do not intersect and their union is all the alphabet.